# Xamarin NavigationDrawer slow

Tags: xamarin

I followed a tutorial on this link : https://github.com/PumpingCode/Xamarin-NavigationDrawerDemo.

It works 100%. But the issue that i'm having is that the application becomes fast for few minutes after launch, but after 5 minutes of navigation it starts to become sluggish. It becomes slow to the extend that the drawer takes +- 3 seconds to open. It also affect other controls such as switch,scrollview - they respond very slowly.

Do you know the possible cause ? How can i diagnose this kind of issue ?

Here is my code below :

**MainActivity**

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        WebView web_view;
        MediaPlayer _player;
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
             try
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);

                // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
                drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);

                // Init toolbar
                var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.app_bar);
                SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.app_name);
                SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

                // Attach item selected handler to navigation view
                var navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
                navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected;

                // Create ActionBarDrawerToggle button and add it to the toolbar
                var drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, Resource.String.open_drawer, Resource.String.close_drawer);
                drawerLayout.SetDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
                drawerToggle.SyncState();

                //load default home screen
                var ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                ft.AddToBackStack(null);
                ft.Add(Resource.Id.HomeFrameLayout, new Accounts());
                ft.Commit();

                if (ft != null)
                    ft.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {  
            }
        }
    }
```

**OnSelectItem**

```
 async void NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ft.AddToBackStack(null);

        switch (e.MenuItem.ItemId)
        {
            case (Resource.Id.nav_incidents):
                SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.toolbar_Accounts);
                ft.Add(Resource.Id.HomeFrameLayout, new Accounts());
                break;
        }

        ft.Commit();

        // Close drawer
        drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();

        if (ft != null)
            ft.Dispose();
    }
```

**Called Fragment - From select item**

```
  public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Accounts, container, false); //specify the page you want to redirect to
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        MemberDetails objMember = null;

        try
        {
            TextView tvAccountStatus = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblAccountStatus);
            TextView tvDateJoined = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblDateJoined);
            TextView tvAccountNo = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblAccountNumber);

            objMember = LocalDB.GetProfileInfo();

            tvDateJoined.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(objMember.AccountDateJoined).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
            tvAccountNo.Text = objMember.ImeiNo;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            Utilities.Dispose(db);
            Utilities.Dispose(objMember);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by leaking native views. Each fragment/view/control you create view new and attach with += to its events etc remains in the memory until you release it.

Make sure each control you create in OnCreate, you dispose and detach from its events in OnDestroy.

So your code should be like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        using (var layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.From (this))
        {
            _FilterItemList = layoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.ActionBarHeaderCentered, null);
        }

        _PageTitle = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textPageHeader);
        _PageTitle.Text = Resources.GetString (Resource.String.about_title);

        // ..
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy ()
    {
        // ...
        if (_PageTitle != null)
        {
            _PageTitle.Dispose ();
            _PageTitle = null;
        }
        ..
    }
```

Comment: I'm still experiencing slow navigation even after disposing the controls and views. I will try tools to monitor leaking memory on Android apps.